# How do I count the total threshold breaches using a Datadog monitor query?

Tags: terraform, datadog

I have this query below for a datadog monitor. The query specifies a latency threshold of 10000ms during put-operations on a map.

However, I would like to monitor how many times the threshold of 10000ms is breached within a 30 minute period and to trigger an alert if the threshold is breached at least 4 times.

How can this query be updated to count the threshold violations in the last 30 minutes?

```
avg(last_10m):sum:hazelcast.imap.local_total_put_latency{env:dev,name:initMap,service:myService} by {host} / sum:hazelcast.imap.local_put_operation_count{env:dev,name:initMap,service:myservice} by {host} > 10000
```

Comment: Please take a look here first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by creating a datadog event monitor to count the number of triggered occurrences of the monitor. So essentially you need two monitors. Surprisingly enough with AppD, this task can be achieved using a single monitor.